# How can you escape the "garbage" elements from the previosly page? (appium android java selenium)

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Appium version:1.13 version, Android version of the phone:9(phone galaxy A10) Java:1.8

Hi!

I am trying to verify a search in an android native application. I thought I could simply take the list of elements after search and to verify that they contain the searched word. But unfortunately, there are some hidden elements (probable garbage from the previous page where all of the elements are showed) and when I extract the list I take the garbage elements as well and I can't filter thought them. (they have the same attributes and they are displayed(.isDisplayed) and I've tried to click them and to filter the list through this but it doesn't always work(depending on what I search) (and select the element has the same behavior as clicking them).
A colleague of mine told me to alt-tab the application and then get back in it but this didn't refresh the page.

Do you people now any other solution? Do you ever experienced this with appium or is this the fault of the app? There is any other solution to refresh the page and the elements in a native android application?

Thx.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the elements are hidden on the page but they will be there in the html, because of this `.isDisplayed` will return true though it's not displayed on the page. Check if the visible elements have any property that's different than hidden elements and use that in your locator strategy to filter only visible elements.

Comment: They have the same attributes. @supputuri (I will put the picture of them in the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to investigate the AppSource better and to find a "parent" that is present only on the wanted page and to search my elements in his hierarchy.